# swift2でHTMLドキュメントを生成

Tags: swift

appledocなどでjavadoc的なものを生成したいのですが、
appledocはまだswift非対応なのか、生成できませんでした。
swift2開発者の皆さまはソースからのドキュメント生成には何を使用されているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift（Objective-Cも）のドキュメント生成ツールはJazzyが最も人気があると思います。

https://github.com/realm/jazzy

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
早速試してみました！
appledocよりも私は好きでした。こちらを使用していきたいと思います。